# CSS submit button and input text don't have the same width

Tags: html, css

Though I made the submit button and the input text exactly:

```
width:60%
```

But when I run the app, they don't have the same width:

```css
.loginClass {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.loginClass ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.loginClass ul li input {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<form class="loginClass">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </li>
  </ul>

</form>
```

Could you please explain and help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because both border-box attributes are different by default..

Use `box-sizing: content-box` on the button, or `box-sizing: border-box` on the Input Elements.

Comment: +1. That I did not know, but then i use the universal "override" by default.

Answer (score -1):

I just added

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and the problem was solved

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrXd5/7/)

Comment: While this is a box-sizing issue, this is a dangerous solution as there may be elements that don't need to be styled with box-sizing.

Comment: Possibly but I use it by default so **all** my elements size correctly as instructed.

Comment: Yea, but you're answering a question for someone else. They don't know the reasoning behind a wildcard and it could cause more issues than they solve. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ while a wildcard box-sizing hack could be useful, lot's of people actually need to use paddings and margins the way the browser naturally renders them.